# Understanding QGIS 3 Print Composer Text Size in Attribute Tables

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

I'm trying to bottom align an attribute table in print composer. Therefore I want to calculate the height of the Table and adjust it's size accordingly.

From my understanding the height of a cell results from the cell margin, the line width of the grid and the text size. Even when setting text size in mm I can't manage to match the cell height to the rulers displayed on the print composer.

Here's my example with cell margin 0,3mm, grid line width 0,3mm and Font size 2mm:
[image: example]

From my understanding, the cell height should be 3,2mm (2x0,3mm + 2x0,3mm + 2mm) but is only a bit more than 3mm.

Any ideas on how to get the actual row height?